# Fixed menu overlps begin of the element

Tags: html, css

I have fixed DIV element at the top of the screen and when I click in menu on item to scroll to a certain DIV so the DIV scrolls but it overlaps begin of the text because of the fixed element.

The code is:

```
<div class="fix">Fixed element</div>
<a href="#element">Link to elemnt's ID</a>

<div id="element">
Begin of the text is here<br>

SOME text
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle of the problem http://jsfiddle.net/dr6rw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the page scrolls to the top of the box. You could push the box's content down by using a [`padding-top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-top) or [`border-top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-top) property as follows:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dr6rw/4/)**

```css
#element {
    height:500px;
    width:400px;

    margin-top:180px;             /* 180px + 20px = 200px */
    border-top: 20px solid white; /* Use a 20px white top border */

    background:red;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thats exactly what I needed. But is there any other solution to do this? Because my element would be too down with this example.

Comment: @user2679576 Well, not really with pure CSS at least in my knowledge. In this particular instance I reduced top margin as 20px to keep the vertical space as it was. If you can update the fiddle with the original (simplified) example, I'll help.

Answer (score 0):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dr6rw/1/)

Add `z-index:1;` to the CSS for `.fix`

*or* if you want the content to overlap the fixed `div`, [**see this example**](http://jsfiddle.net/dr6rw/3/)

---

[**z-Index from MDN:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

> The z-index CSS property specifies the z-order of an element and its
>   descendants. When elements overlap, z-order determines which one
>   covers the other. An element with a larger z-index generally covers an
>   element with a lower one.
>
> For a positioned box, the z-index property specifies:
>
> 1. The stack level of the box in the current stacking context.
> 2. Whether the box establishes a local stacking context.

Comment: I need to have the fixed  div above the red element not in.

Answer (score 0):

the z-index property is your best way to achieve this just set the non-fixed div with a relative positioning and add a z-index greater than the fixed div's z-index

your new css should look like this

```
body {height:1000px;}

.fix {
background:black;
color:white;
position:fixed;
top:0;
width:100%;
z-index:1;
}

a {
position:relative;
top:20px;
}

#element {
height:500px;
width:400px;
margin-top:200px;
background:red; 
z-index:2;      
position:relative; //Relative positioning
}
```